# React Native modal is opening child WebBrowser and Share native views only after closing modal

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, expo

I use React-native and Expo for my mobile client.

**Flow:**

1. User taps to open up a modal from root view
2. Modal has Expo's Share and WebView invoking buttons.
3. When user taps to open either of them, nothing happens.
4. When the modal is closed manually by the user, then the WebBrowser/Share are suddenly invoked, and opened on the root view that the modal is a child of.

Both functions to call the Share and WebBrowser invokers are **in** the modal's controller.

**Partial Content of the modal controller:**

```
openBrowser = (url) => {
  WebBrowser.openBrowserAsync(url);
}
shareModel = (url) => {
  Share.share({
   url: url
  }) .then(console.log(`Shared ${url}`))
  .catch(err => console.log(err))
}


render() {
  return (
  <Modal
      visible={this.props.visible}
      animationType={'slide'}
      onRequestClose={this.props.onRequestClose}
  >
  <View style={styles.modalContainer}>
    <View style={styles.oneButton}>
    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.toolbarButton} onPress={() => this.openBrowser(this.props.model.public_url)}>
      <SimpleLineIcons
            name='globe'
            size={29}
            style={{ marginTop: 1 }}
            color='#7366E3'
        />
      <Text style={{ color: '#7366E3', fontSize: 13, marginTop: 1 }}>View</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  </View>
  </Modal>
 )
}
```

Any ideas? This exact code worked well in the past and something changed.

Comment: This also applies to pure JS alert() function. Alert will open only after modal is closed, but the console logs as if it was ran the moment you pressed the button.

Answer (score 0):

It could be due to the new Expo client's SDK26. One of their breaking changes include methods in the WebBrowser, see https://blog.expo.io/expo-sdk-v26-0-0-is-now-available-2be6d9805b31

Comment: I dont see any refrence to modal blocking all native functions.